# Eclipse DLTK: JDT-like behaviour of parsing and managing files in a project

Tags: eclipse, dltk

i'm developing a plug-in for eclipse using the DLTK framework. This question was asked on the official mailing list but is unanswered yet, so i want to make it more public.

in my DLTK plug-in, as for now, files are only parsed when the editor is opened on a file. Is there a way to achieve a parsing strategy similar to the eclipse jdt in which all files of a project are parsed together? or is that not supported by DLTK and do i have to implement an own strategy and caching model?

thanks in advance.

Comment: I would think that if your file was on the Build Path, the indexer would cause it to be parsed.  But have to you tried the forum? http://eclipse.org/forums/eclipse.technology.dltk

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you mean with "parsed together".
Single file is parsed to understand the file structure (JDT also does it and parses each file independently).
You should care about other files when compiling/validating the sources.
One of the options is contributing your own builder, which will be called with all files on full build and list of changed files on incremental builds.